# Proving if q is odd then (if the square root of (n^q) is irrational then the square root of n is irrational)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

That is the statement that I am trying to prove. I'm really stumped on this one and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried writing it out using more generic notations (p -> (q -> r)) to see if I could simplify the statement at all but really didn't get anywhere doing that. My main problem has to do with the double implies statements, I'm not really sure how to deal with that.

Comment: $p \to ( q \to r)$ is the same as $(p \wedge q) \to r$. Now, try to prove the contrapositive.

Comment: Well one hint.  If $q = 2p $ is even $\sqrt{n^{2p}} = |n|^p$ is not only rational but an integer.  Can you do something similar for $q = 2p + 1$ ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n>0$ be given, $q> 0$ be odd. Then $q = 2k+1$ for some non-negative integer $k$. Then,

$$\sqrt{n^q} = n^k \sqrt{n}.$$

If $\sqrt{n}$ is rational, then $n^k \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n^q}$ is rational, a contradiction on the assumption of the question. Hence $\sqrt{n}$ must be irrational.

This means that if the truth value of "$q$ odd" is $1$, then the truth value of "$\sqrt{n^q}$ irrational $\rightarrow$ $\sqrt{n}$ irrational" is $1$. The (first) implication thus holds.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sqrt{n^q}$ is irrational, substitute 1 for $q$ and since 1 is odd, $\sqrt n$ must also be irrational.